# Copy state object without some fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I need to transfer state of a component to its parent component, but I don't need to transfer all fields.

What I currently do:

```js
submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newState = Object.keys(this.state).map(item => {
        if(item !== 'errors')
        {
            return { item: this.state[item] }
        }
    });

    console.log(newState);
    this.props.onChange(newState);
}
```

Obviously it is not what I need.

```js
state = {
    errors: {
        fio: '',
        email: '',
        phone: ''
    },
    owner: owner.Company,
    fio: null,
    company: null,
    phone: null,
    fax: null,
    email: null,
    adress: null
}
```

I need to transfer all field except `errors`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the rest operator for making it work :)

```
const { errors, ...newState } = this.state;

this.props.onChange(newState);
```

I put an example here :) https://repl.it/@EQuimper/PleasantTrimDeclarations

Comment: I'm happy to know that help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Object destructuring with the rest operator provides a convenient way to copy objects, while omitting specific fields. In the example below, `newState` will be a copy of `this.state`, minus the `errors` property:

```
submitHandler = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { errors, ...newState } = this.state;
  this.props.onChange(newState);
};
```